requests_cache with mongodb closes connection after first request
import requests
import requests_cache
requests_cache.install_cache(
    cache_name='http_cache',
    backend='mongodb',
    connection=MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/'),
    db_name='your_database',
)
# this works fine
requests.get("http://hello.com/1")

# this fails with "Cannot use MongoClient after close")
requests.get("http://hello.com/2")

it works fine with the default sqlite database requests_cache.install_cache()
any idea?

$ python -m test.py
2024-11-01 23:28:22 - pymongo.topology - DEBUG - {"topologyId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "message": "Starting topology monitoring"}
2024-11-01 23:28:22 - pymongo.topology - DEBUG - {"topologyId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "previousDescription": "<TopologyDescription id: 6725560642c795bead9cb3c9, topology_type: Unknown, servers: []>", "newDescription": "<TopologyDescription id: 6725560642c795bead9cb3c9, topology_type: Unknown, servers: [<ServerDescription ('localhost', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None>]>", "message": "Topology description changed"}
2024-11-01 23:28:22 - pymongo.topology - DEBUG - {"topologyId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "serverHost": "localhost", "serverPort": 27017, "message": "Starting server monitoring"}
2024-11-01 23:28:22 - pymongo.connection - DEBUG - {"clientId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "message": "Connection pool created", "serverHost": "localhost", "serverPort": 27017}
2024-11-01 23:28:22 - requests_cache.backends - DEBUG - Initializing backend: mongodb http_cache
2024-11-01 23:28:22 - requests_cache.backends.base - DEBUG - Initialized MongoDict with serializer: SerializerPipeline(name=bson_document, n_stages=1)
2024-11-01 23:28:22 - requests_cache.backends.base - DEBUG - Initialized MongoDict with serializer: None
2024-11-01 23:28:22 - requests_cache.patcher - DEBUG - Patching requests.Session with class: _ConfiguredCachedSession
2024-11-01 23:28:22 - requests_cache.backends - DEBUG - Initializing backend: <MongoCache(name=http_cache)> http_cache
2024-11-01 23:28:22 - pymongo.topology - DEBUG - {"topologyId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "driverConnectionId": 1, "serverHost": "localhost", "serverPort": 27017, "awaited": false, "message": "Server heartbeat started"}
2024-11-01 23:28:22 - requests_cache.policy.actions - DEBUG - Cache directives from request headers: CacheDirectives()
2024-11-01 23:28:22 - requests_cache.policy.actions - DEBUG - Pre-read cache checks: Passed
2024-11-01 23:28:22 - pymongo.serverSelection - DEBUG - {"message": "Server selection started", "selector": "Primary()", "operation": "find", "topologyDescription": "<TopologyDescription id: 6725560642c795bead9cb3c9, topology_type: Unknown, servers: [<ServerDescription ('localhost', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None>]>", "clientId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}}
2024-11-01 23:28:22 - pymongo.serverSelection - DEBUG - {"message": "Waiting for suitable server to become available", "selector": "Primary()", "operation": "find", "topologyDescription": "<TopologyDescription id: 6725560642c795bead9cb3c9, topology_type: Unknown, servers: [<ServerDescription ('localhost', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None>]>", "clientId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "remainingTimeMS": 29}
2024-11-01 23:28:22 - pymongo.topology - DEBUG - {"topologyId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "driverConnectionId": 1, "serverConnectionId": 22985, "serverHost": "localhost", "serverPort": 27017, "awaited": false, "durationMS": 23.08499999344349, "reply": "{\"helloOk\": true, \"ismaster\": true, \"topologyVersion\": {\"processId\": {\"$oid\": \"66ff579b206b63beca3c7cd9\"}}, \"maxBsonObjectSize\": 16777216, \"maxMessageSizeBytes\": 48000000, \"maxWriteBatchSize\": 100000, \"localTime\": {\"$date\": \"2024-11-01T22:28:22.688Z\"}, \"logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes\": 30, \"connectionId\": 22985, \"maxWireVersion\": 13, \"ok\": 1.0}", "message": "Server heartbeat succeeded"}
2024-11-01 23:28:22 - pymongo.connection - DEBUG - {"clientId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "message": "Connection pool ready", "serverHost": "localhost", "serverPort": 27017}
2024-11-01 23:28:22 - pymongo.topology - DEBUG - {"topologyId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "previousDescription": "<TopologyDescription id: 6725560642c795bead9cb3c9, topology_type: Unknown, servers: [<ServerDescription ('localhost', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None>]>", "newDescription": "<TopologyDescription id: 6725560642c795bead9cb3c9, topology_type: Single, servers: [<ServerDescription ('localhost', 27017) server_type: Standalone, rtt: 0.02308499999344349>]>", "message": "Topology description changed"}
2024-11-01 23:28:22 - pymongo.serverSelection - DEBUG - {"message": "Server selection succeeded", "selector": "Primary()", "operation": "find", "topologyDescription": "<TopologyDescription id: 6725560642c795bead9cb3c9, topology_type: Single, servers: [<ServerDescription ('localhost', 27017) server_type: Standalone, rtt: 0.02308499999344349>]>", "clientId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "serverHost": "localhost", "serverPort": 27017}
2024-11-01 23:28:22 - pymongo.connection - DEBUG - {"clientId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "message": "Connection checkout started", "serverHost": "localhost", "serverPort": 27017}
2024-11-01 23:28:22 - pymongo.connection - DEBUG - {"clientId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "message": "Connection created", "serverHost": "localhost", "serverPort": 27017, "driverConnectionId": 1}
2024-11-01 23:28:22 - pymongo.topology - DEBUG - {"topologyId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "driverConnectionId": 1, "serverConnectionId": 22985, "serverHost": "localhost", "serverPort": 27017, "awaited": true, "message": "Server heartbeat started"}
2024-11-01 23:28:22 - pymongo.connection - DEBUG - {"clientId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "message": "Connection ready", "serverHost": "localhost", "serverPort": 27017, "driverConnectionId": 1, "durationMS": 0.001564541831612587}
2024-11-01 23:28:22 - pymongo.connection - DEBUG - {"clientId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "message": "Connection checked out", "serverHost": "localhost", "serverPort": 27017, "driverConnectionId": 1, "durationMS": 0.0020183329470455647}
2024-11-01 23:28:22 - pymongo.command - DEBUG - {"clientId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "message": "Command started", "command": "{\"find\": \"responses\", \"filter\": {\"_id\": \"dafc122aabe5ed3c\"}, \"limit\": 1, \"singleBatch\": true, \"lsid\": {\"id\": {\"$binary\": {\"base64\": \"rmEEnpgzR0uDjEz4gYuikw==\", \"subType\": \"04\"}}}, \"$db\": \"http_cache\"}", "commandName": "find", "databaseName": "http_cache", "requestId": 1144108930, "operationId": 1144108930, "driverConnectionId": 1, "serverConnectionId": 22987, "serverHost": "localhost", "serverPort": 27017}
2024-11-01 23:28:22 - pymongo.command - DEBUG - {"clientId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "message": "Command succeeded", "durationMS": 4.861, "reply": "{\"cursor\": {\"ns\": \"http_cache.responses\"}, \"ok\": 1.0}", "commandName": "find", "databaseName": "http_cache", "requestId": 1144108930, "operationId": 1144108930, "driverConnectionId": 1, "serverConnectionId": 22987, "serverHost": "localhost", "serverPort": 27017}
2024-11-01 23:28:22 - pymongo.connection - DEBUG - {"clientId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "message": "Connection checked in", "serverHost": "localhost", "serverPort": 27017, "driverConnectionId": 1}
2024-11-01 23:28:22 - pymongo.serverSelection - DEBUG - {"message": "Server selection started", "selector": "Primary()", "operation": "find", "topologyDescription": "<TopologyDescription id: 6725560642c795bead9cb3c9, topology_type: Single, servers: [<ServerDescription ('localhost', 27017) server_type: Standalone, rtt: 0.02308499999344349>]>", "clientId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}}
2024-11-01 23:28:22 - pymongo.serverSelection - DEBUG - {"message": "Server selection succeeded", "selector": "Primary()", "operation": "find", "topologyDescription": "<TopologyDescription id: 6725560642c795bead9cb3c9, topology_type: Single, servers: [<ServerDescription ('localhost', 27017) server_type: Standalone, rtt: 0.02308499999344349>]>", "clientId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "serverHost": "localhost", "serverPort": 27017}
2024-11-01 23:28:22 - pymongo.connection - DEBUG - {"clientId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "message": "Connection checkout started", "serverHost": "localhost", "serverPort": 27017}
2024-11-01 23:28:22 - pymongo.connection - DEBUG - {"clientId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "message": "Connection checked out", "serverHost": "localhost", "serverPort": 27017, "driverConnectionId": 1, "durationMS": 3.2084062695503235e-05}
2024-11-01 23:28:22 - pymongo.command - DEBUG - {"clientId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "message": "Command started", "command": "{\"find\": \"redirects\", \"filter\": {\"_id\": \"dafc122aabe5ed3c\"}, \"limit\": 1, \"singleBatch\": true, \"lsid\": {\"id\": {\"$binary\": {\"base64\": \"rmEEnpgzR0uDjEz4gYuikw==\", \"subType\": \"04\"}}}, \"$db\": \"http_cache\"}", "commandName": "find", "databaseName": "http_cache", "requestId": 470211272, "operationId": 470211272, "driverConnectionId": 1, "serverConnectionId": 22987, "serverHost": "localhost", "serverPort": 27017}
2024-11-01 23:28:22 - pymongo.command - DEBUG - {"clientId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "message": "Command succeeded", "durationMS": 0.71, "reply": "{\"cursor\": {\"ns\": \"http_cache.redirects\"}, \"ok\": 1.0}", "commandName": "find", "databaseName": "http_cache", "requestId": 470211272, "operationId": 470211272, "driverConnectionId": 1, "serverConnectionId": 22987, "serverHost": "localhost", "serverPort": 27017}
2024-11-01 23:28:22 - pymongo.connection - DEBUG - {"clientId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "message": "Connection checked in", "serverHost": "localhost", "serverPort": 27017, "driverConnectionId": 1}
2024-11-01 23:28:22 - requests_cache.policy.actions - DEBUG - Post-read cache actions: CacheActions(expire_after=-1, send_request=True)
2024-11-01 23:28:22 - urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG - Starting new HTTP connection (1): hello.com:80
2024-11-01 23:28:22 - urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG - http://hello.com:80 "GET /1 HTTP/1.1" 302 0
2024-11-01 23:28:22 - requests_cache.policy.actions - DEBUG - Cache directives from request headers: CacheDirectives()
2024-11-01 23:28:22 - requests_cache.policy.actions - DEBUG - Pre-read cache checks: Passed
2024-11-01 23:28:22 - pymongo.serverSelection - DEBUG - {"message": "Server selection started", "selector": "Primary()", "operation": "find", "topologyDescription": "<TopologyDescription id: 6725560642c795bead9cb3c9, topology_type: Single, servers: [<ServerDescription ('localhost', 27017) server_type: Standalone, rtt: 0.02308499999344349>]>", "clientId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}}
2024-11-01 23:28:22 - pymongo.serverSelection - DEBUG - {"message": "Server selection succeeded", "selector": "Primary()", "operation": "find", "topologyDescription": "<TopologyDescription id: 6725560642c795bead9cb3c9, topology_type: Single, servers: [<ServerDescription ('localhost', 27017) server_type: Standalone, rtt: 0.02308499999344349>]>", "clientId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "serverHost": "localhost", "serverPort": 27017}
2024-11-01 23:28:22 - pymongo.connection - DEBUG - {"clientId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "message": "Connection checkout started", "serverHost": "localhost", "serverPort": 27017}
2024-11-01 23:28:22 - pymongo.connection - DEBUG - {"clientId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "message": "Connection checked out", "serverHost": "localhost", "serverPort": 27017, "driverConnectionId": 1, "durationMS": 8.499994874000549e-05}
2024-11-01 23:28:22 - pymongo.command - DEBUG - {"clientId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "message": "Command started", "command": "{\"find\": \"responses\", \"filter\": {\"_id\": \"7e7eed280d581544\"}, \"limit\": 1, \"singleBatch\": true, \"lsid\": {\"id\": {\"$binary\": {\"base64\": \"rmEEnpgzR0uDjEz4gYuikw==\", \"subType\": \"04\"}}}, \"$db\": \"http_cache\"}", "commandName": "find", "databaseName": "http_cache", "requestId": 101027544, "operationId": 101027544, "driverConnectionId": 1, "serverConnectionId": 22987, "serverHost": "localhost", "serverPort": 27017}
2024-11-01 23:28:22 - pymongo.command - DEBUG - {"clientId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "message": "Command succeeded", "durationMS": 0.983, "reply": "{\"cursor\": {\"ns\": \"http_cache.responses\"}, \"ok\": 1.0}", "commandName": "find", "databaseName": "http_cache", "requestId": 101027544, "operationId": 101027544, "driverConnectionId": 1, "serverConnectionId": 22987, "serverHost": "localhost", "serverPort": 27017}
2024-11-01 23:28:22 - pymongo.connection - DEBUG - {"clientId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "message": "Connection checked in", "serverHost": "localhost", "serverPort": 27017, "driverConnectionId": 1}
2024-11-01 23:28:22 - pymongo.serverSelection - DEBUG - {"message": "Server selection started", "selector": "Primary()", "operation": "find", "topologyDescription": "<TopologyDescription id: 6725560642c795bead9cb3c9, topology_type: Single, servers: [<ServerDescription ('localhost', 27017) server_type: Standalone, rtt: 0.02308499999344349>]>", "clientId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}}
2024-11-01 23:28:22 - pymongo.serverSelection - DEBUG - {"message": "Server selection succeeded", "selector": "Primary()", "operation": "find", "topologyDescription": "<TopologyDescription id: 6725560642c795bead9cb3c9, topology_type: Single, servers: [<ServerDescription ('localhost', 27017) server_type: Standalone, rtt: 0.02308499999344349>]>", "clientId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "serverHost": "localhost", "serverPort": 27017}
2024-11-01 23:28:22 - pymongo.connection - DEBUG - {"clientId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "message": "Connection checkout started", "serverHost": "localhost", "serverPort": 27017}
2024-11-01 23:28:22 - pymongo.connection - DEBUG - {"clientId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "message": "Connection checked out", "serverHost": "localhost", "serverPort": 27017, "driverConnectionId": 1, "durationMS": 0.0002238750457763672}
2024-11-01 23:28:22 - pymongo.command - DEBUG - {"clientId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "message": "Command started", "command": "{\"find\": \"redirects\", \"filter\": {\"_id\": \"7e7eed280d581544\"}, \"limit\": 1, \"singleBatch\": true, \"lsid\": {\"id\": {\"$binary\": {\"base64\": \"rmEEnpgzR0uDjEz4gYuikw==\", \"subType\": \"04\"}}}, \"$db\": \"http_cache\"}", "commandName": "find", "databaseName": "http_cache", "requestId": 1457850878, "operationId": 1457850878, "driverConnectionId": 1, "serverConnectionId": 22987, "serverHost": "localhost", "serverPort": 27017}
2024-11-01 23:28:22 - pymongo.command - DEBUG - {"clientId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "message": "Command succeeded", "durationMS": 0.6769999999999999, "reply": "{\"cursor\": {\"ns\": \"http_cache.redirects\"}, \"ok\": 1.0}", "commandName": "find", "databaseName": "http_cache", "requestId": 1457850878, "operationId": 1457850878, "driverConnectionId": 1, "serverConnectionId": 22987, "serverHost": "localhost", "serverPort": 27017}
2024-11-01 23:28:22 - pymongo.connection - DEBUG - {"clientId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "message": "Connection checked in", "serverHost": "localhost", "serverPort": 27017, "driverConnectionId": 1}
2024-11-01 23:28:22 - requests_cache.policy.actions - DEBUG - Post-read cache actions: CacheActions(expire_after=-1, send_request=True)
2024-11-01 23:28:22 - urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG - Starting new HTTPS connection (1): hello.com:443
2024-11-01 23:28:23 - urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG - https://hello.com:443 "GET /1 HTTP/1.1" 404 278
2024-11-01 23:28:23 - requests_cache.policy.actions - DEBUG - Pre-write cache checks: disabled status
2024-11-01 23:28:23 - requests_cache.session - DEBUG - Skipping cache write for URL: https://hello.com/1
2024-11-01 23:28:23 - requests_cache.policy.actions - DEBUG - Pre-write cache checks: disabled status
2024-11-01 23:28:23 - requests_cache.session - DEBUG - Skipping cache write for URL: http://hello.com/1
2024-11-01 23:28:23 - requests_cache.backends.base - DEBUG - Closing backend connections
2024-11-01 23:28:23 - pymongo.serverSelection - DEBUG - {"message": "Server selection started", "selector": "PrimaryPreferred(tag_sets=None, max_staleness=-1, hedge=None)", "operation": "endSessions", "topologyDescription": "<TopologyDescription id: 6725560642c795bead9cb3c9, topology_type: Single, servers: [<ServerDescription ('localhost', 27017) server_type: Standalone, rtt: 0.02308499999344349>]>", "clientId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}}
2024-11-01 23:28:23 - pymongo.serverSelection - DEBUG - {"message": "Server selection succeeded", "selector": "PrimaryPreferred(tag_sets=None, max_staleness=-1, hedge=None)", "operation": "endSessions", "topologyDescription": "<TopologyDescription id: 6725560642c795bead9cb3c9, topology_type: Single, servers: [<ServerDescription ('localhost', 27017) server_type: Standalone, rtt: 0.02308499999344349>]>", "clientId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "serverHost": "localhost", "serverPort": 27017}
2024-11-01 23:28:23 - pymongo.connection - DEBUG - {"clientId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "message": "Connection checkout started", "serverHost": "localhost", "serverPort": 27017}
2024-11-01 23:28:23 - pymongo.connection - DEBUG - {"clientId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "message": "Connection checked out", "serverHost": "localhost", "serverPort": 27017, "driverConnectionId": 1, "durationMS": 0.00010349997319281101}
2024-11-01 23:28:23 - pymongo.command - DEBUG - {"clientId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "message": "Command started", "command": "{\"endSessions\": [{\"id\": {\"$binary\": {\"base64\": \"rmEEnpgzR0uDjEz4gYuikw==\", \"subType\": \"04\"}}}], \"$db\": \"admin\"}", "commandName": "endSessions", "databaseName": "admin", "requestId": 1458777923, "operationId": 1458777923, "driverConnectionId": 1, "serverConnectionId": 22987, "serverHost": "localhost", "serverPort": 27017}
2024-11-01 23:28:23 - pymongo.command - DEBUG - {"clientId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "message": "Command succeeded", "durationMS": 2.462, "reply": "{\"ok\": 1.0}", "commandName": "endSessions", "databaseName": "admin", "requestId": 1458777923, "operationId": 1458777923, "driverConnectionId": 1, "serverConnectionId": 22987, "serverHost": "localhost", "serverPort": 27017}
2024-11-01 23:28:23 - pymongo.connection - DEBUG - {"clientId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "message": "Connection checked in", "serverHost": "localhost", "serverPort": 27017, "driverConnectionId": 1}
2024-11-01 23:28:23 - pymongo.topology - DEBUG - {"topologyId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "serverHost": "localhost", "serverPort": 27017, "message": "Stopped server monitoring"}
2024-11-01 23:28:23 - pymongo.connection - DEBUG - {"clientId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "message": "Connection closed", "serverHost": "localhost", "serverPort": 27017, "driverConnectionId": 1, "reason": "Connection pool was closed", "error": "poolClosed"}
2024-11-01 23:28:23 - pymongo.connection - DEBUG - {"clientId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "message": "Connection pool closed", "serverHost": "localhost", "serverPort": 27017}
2024-11-01 23:28:23 - pymongo.topology - DEBUG - {"topologyId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "previousDescription": "<TopologyDescription id: 6725560642c795bead9cb3c9, topology_type: Single, servers: [<ServerDescription ('localhost', 27017) server_type: Standalone, rtt: 0.02308499999344349>]>", "newDescription": "<TopologyDescription id: 6725560642c795bead9cb3c9, topology_type: Single, servers: [<ServerDescription ('localhost', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None>]>", "message": "Topology description changed"}
2024-11-01 23:28:23 - pymongo.topology - DEBUG - {"topologyId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "message": "Stopped topology monitoring"}
2024-11-01 23:28:23 - pymongo.topology - DEBUG - {"topologyId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "serverHost": "localhost", "serverPort": 27017, "message": "Stopped server monitoring"}
2024-11-01 23:28:23 - pymongo.topology - DEBUG - {"topologyId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "previousDescription": "<TopologyDescription id: 6725560642c795bead9cb3c9, topology_type: Single, servers: [<ServerDescription ('localhost', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None>]>", "newDescription": "<TopologyDescription id: 6725560642c795bead9cb3c9, topology_type: Single, servers: [<ServerDescription ('localhost', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None>]>", "message": "Topology description changed"}
2024-11-01 23:28:23 - pymongo.topology - DEBUG - {"topologyId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "message": "Stopped topology monitoring"}
2024-11-01 23:28:23 - requests_cache.backends - DEBUG - Initializing backend: <MongoCache(name=http_cache)> http_cache
2024-11-01 23:28:23 - requests_cache.policy.actions - DEBUG - Cache directives from request headers: CacheDirectives()
2024-11-01 23:28:23 - requests_cache.policy.actions - DEBUG - Pre-read cache checks: Passed
2024-11-01 23:28:23 - pymongo.serverSelection - DEBUG - {"message": "Server selection started", "selector": "Primary()", "operation": "find", "topologyDescription": "<TopologyDescription id: 6725560642c795bead9cb3c9, topology_type: Single, servers: [<ServerDescription ('localhost', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None>]>", "clientId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}}
2024-11-01 23:28:23 - pymongo.serverSelection - DEBUG - {"message": "Waiting for suitable server to become available", "selector": "Primary()", "operation": "find", "topologyDescription": "<TopologyDescription id: 6725560642c795bead9cb3c9, topology_type: Single, servers: [<ServerDescription ('localhost', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None>]>", "clientId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "remainingTimeMS": 29}
2024-11-01 23:28:23 - requests_cache.backends.base - DEBUG - Closing backend connections
2024-11-01 23:28:23 - pymongo.topology - DEBUG - {"topologyId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "serverHost": "localhost", "serverPort": 27017, "message": "Stopped server monitoring"}
2024-11-01 23:28:23 - pymongo.topology - DEBUG - {"topologyId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "previousDescription": "<TopologyDescription id: 6725560642c795bead9cb3c9, topology_type: Single, servers: [<ServerDescription ('localhost', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None>]>", "newDescription": "<TopologyDescription id: 6725560642c795bead9cb3c9, topology_type: Single, servers: [<ServerDescription ('localhost', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None>]>", "message": "Topology description changed"}
2024-11-01 23:28:23 - pymongo.topology - DEBUG - {"topologyId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "message": "Stopped topology monitoring"}
2024-11-01 23:28:23 - pymongo.topology - DEBUG - {"topologyId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "serverHost": "localhost", "serverPort": 27017, "message": "Stopped server monitoring"}
2024-11-01 23:28:23 - pymongo.topology - DEBUG - {"topologyId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "previousDescription": "<TopologyDescription id: 6725560642c795bead9cb3c9, topology_type: Single, servers: [<ServerDescription ('localhost', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None>]>", "newDescription": "<TopologyDescription id: 6725560642c795bead9cb3c9, topology_type: Single, servers: [<ServerDescription ('localhost', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None>]>", "message": "Topology description changed"}
2024-11-01 23:28:23 - pymongo.topology - DEBUG - {"topologyId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "message": "Stopped topology monitoring"}
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
File "/test/test.py", line 13, in <module>
  requests.get("http://hello.com/2")
File "/test/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 75, in get
  return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/test/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
  return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/test/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/requests_cache/session.py", line 183, in request
  return super().request(method, url, *args, headers=headers, **kwargs)  # type: ignore
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/test/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
  resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/test/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/requests_cache/session.py", line 218, in send
  cached_response = self.cache.get_response(actions.cache_key)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/test/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/requests_cache/backends/base.py", line 77, in get_response
  response = self.responses.get(key)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "<frozen _collections_abc>", line 807, in get
File "/test/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/requests_cache/backends/mongodb.py", line 120, in __getitem__
  result = self.collection.find_one({'_id': key})
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/test/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pymongo/synchronous/collection.py", line 1730, in find_one
  for result in cursor.limit(-1):
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/test/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pymongo/synchronous/cursor.py", line 1281, in __next__
  return self.next()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/test/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pymongo/synchronous/cursor.py", line 1257, in next
  if len(self._data) or self._refresh():
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/test/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pymongo/synchronous/cursor.py", line 1205, in _refresh
  self._send_message(q)
File "/test/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pymongo/synchronous/cursor.py", line 1100, in _send_message
  response = client._run_operation(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/test/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pymongo/_csot.py", line 119, in csot_wrapper
  return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/test/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pymongo/synchronous/mongo_client.py", line 1754, in _run_operation
  return self._retryable_read(
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/test/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pymongo/synchronous/mongo_client.py", line 1863, in _retryable_read
  return self._retry_internal(
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/test/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pymongo/_csot.py", line 119, in csot_wrapper
  return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/test/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pymongo/synchronous/mongo_client.py", line 1830, in _retry_internal
  ).run()
    ^^^^^
File "/test/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pymongo/synchronous/mongo_client.py", line 2554, in run
  return self._read() if self._is_read else self._write()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/test/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pymongo/synchronous/mongo_client.py", line 2689, in _read
  self._server = self._get_server()
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/test/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pymongo/synchronous/mongo_client.py", line 2645, in _get_server
  return self._client._select_server(
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/test/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pymongo/synchronous/mongo_client.py", line 1649, in _select_server
  server = topology.select_server(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/test/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pymongo/synchronous/topology.py", line 398, in select_server
  server = self._select_server(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/test/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pymongo/synchronous/topology.py", line 376, in _select_server
  servers = self.select_servers(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/test/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pymongo/synchronous/topology.py", line 283, in select_servers
  server_descriptions = self._select_servers_loop(
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/test/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pymongo/synchronous/topology.py", line 350, in _select_servers_loop
  self._ensure_opened()
File "/test/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pymongo/synchronous/topology.py", line 774, in _ensure_opened
  raise InvalidOperation("Cannot use MongoClient after close")
pymongo.errors.InvalidOperation: Cannot use MongoClient after close
2024-11-01 23:28:23 - pymongo.topology - DEBUG - {"topologyId": {"$oid": "6725560642c795bead9cb3c9"}, "serverHost": "localhost", "serverPort": 27017, "awaited": true, "durationMS": 501.28891598433256, "failure": "\"_OperationCancelled('operation cancelled')\"", "message": "Server heartbeat failed"}
```


